# Why didn't Inadu's curse effect Hope Mikaelson?

Tags: character, the-vampire-diaries, the-originals

In *The Originals* season 4, we got to know that it was Inadu who started the werewolf curse and the reason why seven original bloodlines of werewolves exist with the Crescent Wolf Pack being the first one. The whole Crescent pack was effected by it including Hayley, but how did Hope bypass that curse? She even got the Crescent birth mark like Hayley but she ends up as a witch tribrid and didn't have any effect of Inadu's curse. And as we learn from The Vampire Diaries you can be either be a Witch or a Vampire/Werewolf, not both except Siphoners and Hope is surely not a Siphoner.

So how did Hope bypass Inadu's curse, especial when she was form the first cursed wolf pack?